# Hashing and salts of pickle in python

Tags: python, hash, pickle, salt

i have the scripts for salts and hashing password

how i can use it for a specific file?
My file is a dictionnary on python  : a pikle

```
import hashlib, binascii, os

def hash_password(password):
    salt = hashlib.sha256(os.urandom(60)).hexdigest().encode('ascii')
    password_hash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512',password.encode('utf-8'),
    salt,100000)
    password_hash = binascii.hexlify(password_hash)
    return (salt+password_hash).decode('ascii')

def check_password(sored_password, user_password):
    salt = stored_password[:64]
    stored_password = stored_password[64:]
    password_hash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512',user_password.encode('utf-8'),
    salt.encode('ascii'),
    100000)
    password_hash = binascii.hexlify(password_hash).decode('ascii')
    return password_hash == stored_password

stored_password = hash_password('MyPassword')
print(stored_password)
print(check_password(stored_password,'MyPassword'))
print(check_password(stored_password,'WrongPassword'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the argument of your `check_password` function. The parameter should be `stored_password`:

```py
import hashlib, binascii, os

def hash_password(password):
    salt = hashlib.sha256(os.urandom(60)).hexdigest().encode('ascii')
    password_hash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512',password.encode('utf-8'),
    salt,100000)
    password_hash = binascii.hexlify(password_hash)
    return (salt+password_hash).decode('ascii')

def check_password(stored_password, user_password):
    salt = stored_password[:64]
    stored_password = stored_password[64:]
    password_hash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512',user_password.encode('utf-8'),
    salt.encode('ascii'),
    100000)
    password_hash = binascii.hexlify(password_hash).decode('ascii')
    return password_hash == stored_password

stored_password = hash_password('MyPassword')
print(stored_password)
print(check_password(stored_password,'MyPassword'))
print(check_password(stored_password,'WrongPassword'))
```

Comment: Thanks , i need to use this code for a pickle (dictionary on python ) How i can use it?

Comment: You should ask a new question and explain what exactly you need to do. I think that this your question is answered.